# How do I manually find the storage slot for a string greater than 32 bytes?

Tags: evm, storage, string, keccak, slots

**This is my contract:**

```
SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.22; 
contract StringStorage { 
    
    string short_string = "ABCD"; 
    string long_string = "ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD"; //84 characters long ; 
    
}
```

How do I get the first storage slot of long_string? I tried doing keccak256(0x00…01) in an online keccak256 calculator but it returned **cb371be217faa47dab94e0d0ff0840c6cbf41645f0dc1a6ae3f34447155a76f3** however when I look in remix IDE debugger it says the slot is **0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6**. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?? I thought the slot of a string greater than 31 bytes was the keccak hash of its slot??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to get the address of the storage slot in Remix:

```
function a(uint256 slot) external pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encode(slot));
}
```

This will return `0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6`

If you use Foundry: `cast keccak 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` This will also bring back the correct sequence

The online calculator will also return the correct value if the input parameters are correct

[image]

And here's a long string in the storages
[image]

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot more sense now.